# Cannot make a label visible in Access 2010 even though it was only made invisible in the same form: Error 2467

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a "Main Menu" form that uses `Me.lblProjects.Visible = False` within an `On Load` sub (with two other labels) and want to make those labels visible again when myself or other users log in.  This first part, the setting to 'invisble', works.  However, when I insert `Me.lblProjects.Visble = True` at the end of the `If Then Else` security login sub, I get a Run-time Error 2467 telling me it refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist. I cannot find a solution in the previous answers so any assistance or clarity would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think I may have some of the answer:  the On Load event is for the form but the Login is in the Form Header.  I've only realised this may have an impact because I've moved the Exit control into the Form Footer and that's stopped working as it had.

Comment: Post full procedure code for review. Edit your question to include additional information. What previous answers?

Comment: Hi YowE2K, the Comment box is telling me my code is too long.  In passing, I've been told the Email Client Server has problems and that it could be impacting other server software. Until that's resolved, I'll discontinue this thread in case it is just a hardware problem.  Thanks for offering to assist me.